# How do I target these boxes? (image attached)

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors

I am trying to target the boxes with the white dots in them. Every black box in this image is a blog post **including the larger one on top**. Initially, I thought of using `nth-child` but honestly am not sure how to arrange it or what numbers to use. I'm sure jQuery is an option. If anybody out there can help me out, I'd be very grateful. Thank you.

[image: boxes]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretend the white dot is a blue background, for this example (JQuery):

```
$('div').not(':first-child').filter(':odd').css('background-color','blue');
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/R5MJ3/

Comment: I see it working in your example but for some reason, I had to change 'odd' to 'even' for it to work for me. `$('article').not(':first-child').filter(':even').addClass('right');` Either way, thanks!

Comment: Actually, changing `first-child` to `first` and keeping `odd` also worked. Why would `first-child` not work? Any ideas?

Comment: @J82 - `:first-child` and `:odd` are an unnatural couple. `:first-child` refers to DOM structure, and `:odd` (or `:first`) refer to the order in which elements are found. Using `:first` is probably better here.

Comment: While :first matches only a single element, the :first-child selector can match more than one: one for each parent. It's probably the way your div structure differed than my example. Glad it was able to help you nonetheless :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be extra clever, you can use:

```
$('div:nth-child(2n+3)')
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/R5MJ3/1/

However, that might be considered less readable/understandable than AlienWebguy's answer.